# AWS Amplify React Native, throwing 403 InvalidSignatureException when passing data to request

Tags: react-native, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify

We create an API for authenticated identities only. so the only valid user can access it. the API is throwing 403 InvalidSignatureException whenever there is data in the body of any request.

we also tested the API on native Android. it is working fine with that.

our POST request code is the following,

```
API.post(apiName, path, {body:{key:value}}).then(response => {
    consoloe.log(response);
}).catch(error => {
    consoloe.log(error);
});
```

We have followed everything on GitHub and API gateway but not getting proper solution for it.

Comment: having the same issue. Did u fix this yet?

Comment: still having same issue

Answer (score 0):

I also received the `InvalidSignatureException`.

I can't tell for sure what the issue is with your request, but I solved my problem by looking at the error response and figured out that my region was wrong (us_east_1 instead of us-east-1).

Try the following:

```
API.post(apiName, path, {body:{key:value}}).then(response => {
    console.log(response);
}).catch(error => {
    console.log(error.response); // <--
});
```

In my case the `error.response` was:

[image: Response from API call]

And under `data.message` the error was described

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was just getting 403 with no message. After 30 mins I realised that my `path` variable was missing slash.